# Logback does not write log into the file but console

Tags: logback

I do not know why logback writes log into the console, please help thanks.

```
<configuration debug="true" scan="true">



    <appender name="FILE"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>/log/%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} -
                %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ASYNC" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        <includeCallerData>true</includeCallerData>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="ASYNC" />
    </root>

    <root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="ASYNC" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Why do you have multiple ROOT elements?

Answer (score 0):

You have named both your appender the same ref="FILE" and your root level loggers as "ASYNC"