# logback not logging to console at all

Tags: java, logging, logback, apache-storm

I cannot log to the console using logback. Nothing is showing up when I run my application.

here my **logback** file content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <Pattern>
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} -
            %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </layout>
</appender>



<root level="error">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>
<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>
```

for example I can't get the message "Starting debugging":

```
logger.debug("Starting debugging");

        ConnectorTopology ConnectorTopology= new ConnectorTopology();
```

and my topology of storm is working 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never use multiple root-elements. Remove one of them and set the level of the remaining one to DEBUG.

Also the pattern-tag should be enclosed in an encoder-tag, not a layout-tag:

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
  <encoder>
    <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
  </encoder>
</appender>
```

See the manual for more details: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#ConsoleAppender

Comment: thanks, but it's not wokring, when i tried to log into a file, look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17480729/logback-does-not-write-log-into-the-file-but-console

Comment: sorry: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36935230/logback-does-not-creates-log-file

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

***Note:*** This answer is applicable if you are using LogBack along with Gradle(build tool). If you have set the LogBack log level to DEBUG, you can proceed to check the Gradle log level next.

***Problem:*** The default log level in Gradle is LIFECYCLE, which prints the progress information only

***Solution:***
Please change the log level to print more logs. When you run the application using any build tool like Gradle, please use

```
gradlew clean build --info
```

or

```
gradlew clean build --debug
```